# SQL default value constraint INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I have a column in my table which have a default value constraint 'DF_DOC_DMA_PLACE_1_dma_id'

I want to drop that column but first I need to drop that constraint. The problem is that this table resides in many databases and in some of them the constraint does not exist. How to first check if the constrain exists, then delete it ?

I'm aware of the views in INFORMATION_SCHEMA but I can't find the view with this constraint? Can u tell me where the default value constraints resides ? Thanks

Comment: by the way, just an hint: information_schema are ANSI views which sql server does have, still if you are working just with ms sql server it's better if you use the sys. views, which are sql-server-only views and are well documented on msdn ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following query to find the default constraint for a every table.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc = 'DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something based upon what you will find with this...

```
select t.name as 'table', c.[name] as 'column' ,dc.[name],dc.[definition]
from sys.tables as t
join sys.columns as c on (c.[object_id] = t.[object_id])
join sys.default_constraints as dc on (dc.[object_id] = c.[default_object_id])
```

Comment: Is there a way to also list any stored procs that use the column mentioned?